# Dynamically excluding field from Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.0

I want to exclude, programatically, a field in my form.
Currently I have this:

```
class RandomForm(BaseForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # This doesn't work
        if kwargs["instance"] is None:
            self._meta.exclude = ("active",)

        super(ServiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # This doesn't work either
        if kwargs["instance"] is None:
            self._meta.exclude = ("active",)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Service
        fields = (...some fields...)
```

How can I exclude the `active` field only when a new model is being created?

Comment: Just to clarify: not working means the field keeps apearing in the form even if the line `self._meta.exclude = ("active",)` gets executed? Or are you getting errors?

Comment: And is it just a typo or is `RandomForm` really calling the super method from `ServiceForm` ?

Comment: @Ralf Indeed. "Doesn't work" means that the field keeps showing. Also, yes, that's a typo.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can solve it this way:

```
class RandomForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RandomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.instance:
            self.fields.pop('active')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Service
        fields = (...some fields...)
```

Comment: That will override the verbose_name, default value and so on in my model.

Comment: @alexandernst I didn't have chance to test it, but try `if not self.instance: self.fields.pop('active')`. You should add `active` to meta's fields also.

Comment: With Django 3.2, `if not self.instance` is false even for new instances. Changing the condition to `if not self.instance.id` will achieve the expected behavior.

Answer (score -5):

Django ModelForm provides `exclude` attribute. Have you tried that?

```
class RandomForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Service
        exclude = ['is_active']
```

Comment: didn't dv but I think the OP means with "dynamically" that depending on some properties (for example whether the instance already exists), the form should render differently, so we can *reuse* the *same* form, but it will display different fields.